# Remove nodes from the graph without reloading the web page in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a graph of molecular interactions that takes nodes and edges from a query to my database. I also have two buttons as node labels: "Remove" and "Add" (where "remove" should remove the selected node, while "add" should expand to first neighbors).
I would like to add a function that removes the selected node (on click) without reloading the web page, but just reloading the graph (I want the selected node to disappear from the graph). So, the problem is not the function cy.remove but rather the graph reloading.
I am new to cytoscape.js (let's say to javascript), so I have no idea on how to reload a graph and where to put the remove and reload functions. To date I am only able to pass the ID of the node I want to remove and/or expand via GET method using php. This actually works, but it reloads the web page making a new query to my database, and it becomes tricky when one wants to add and remove a lot of nodes.
Could anyone provide me some simple example code that explains how to reload a graph after a button click, keeping all nodes except the removed one?
Sorry if it is a stupid question
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button_deleteNode').click(function(){
    cy.remove(nodeID);
});
```